# Browser can't recognize my Defined JS Variable when JS Code is Linked

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typeerror, dom-manipulation

For some reason, my browser cannot read the variable I declared with contents of the HTML DOM. My code doesn't work when I use Microsoft's Live Preview extension to open my work in a browser window. However, if I open the html file in a browser window(show preivew(external browser)) and then import the content of my js file into the console instead of having the js file immediately linked, it works.

For the latter situation, I only get this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null'

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="challenge1Copy.js"></script>
        <title>Changing Doc Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

        </header>
        <p>Some example code</p>
        <!--button meant to call event handler-->
        <button>Click here!</button>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js code

```
//Displays the current time and date
const day = new Date();
//Displays the current hours
let hours = day.getHours();
//Displays the current minutes
const minutes = day.getMinutes();
//Displays the current seconds
const seconds = day.getSeconds();
//Displays the current day as a number value
let currentDay = day.getDay();

//Changes the number value of the day into a word format
switch (currentDay) {
  case 0:
    currentDay = 'Sunday';
    break;
  case 1:
    currentDay = 'Monday';
    break;
  case 2:
    currentDay = 'Tuesday';
    break;
  case 3:
    currentDay = 'Wednesday';
    break;
  case 4:
    currentDay = 'Thursday';
    break;
  case 5:
    currentDay = 'Friday';
    break;
  case 6:
    currentDay = 'Saturday';
    break;
  Default:
    console.log('currentDay variable is not working')
    break;
}

//Declaring and defining a time suffix variable to be able to display am and pm
let timeSuffix = '';

//Setting terms for when to use am and when to use pm
if (hours >= 12) {
  timeSuffix = 'PM';
} else {
  timeSuffix = 'AM';
}

//Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time format
if (hours > 12) {
  hours = hours - 12;
}

//finds button in html doc
let realButton = document.querySelector('button');

//event to change paragraph content to current date and time
realButton.addEventListener('click', function (e){
  let dayAndTime = document.querySelector('p')
  dayAndTime.innerText = `Today is : ${currentDay}.\nCurrent time is : ${hours} ${timeSuffix} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
})
```

I just want to figure out why my js code works only when manually injected into the console when the html file is open in a browser. This seems to be the only case in which my code works at all.

Comment: Place the script tag at the end of your markup (before `</ body>`) otherwise it will be executed before all the dom content has loaded. That is why you are getting the cannot read property of null error. Alternatively you could add the defer attribute to your script tag.